# Use of %TYPE in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, alter-table

In PL/SQL, the [`%TYPE` attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/type_attribute.htm) can be used to declare a variable as the same datatype as a column in a table.  Can the same, or a similar function, be used in SQL?  For example, creating the  in an `ALTER TABLE` statement, for example:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name another_table.column%TYPE;
```

Is there any way to do this?  Attempting to run the above code (with corrected parameters) yields:

> ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: Not in plain SQL. You could do it dynamically through PL/SQL (but not with that syntax though). Is that acceptable? Or is it really necessary? I would think schema changes would be controlled enough that you know the types involved.

Comment: Probably you have to execute that in a PLSQL block. Just wrap the statement in `begin - end`

Comment: @AlexPoole @Evgeni  | Putting the code in a PL/SQL block failed with `ORA-06550` and `PLS-00103` errors, while `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` failed with the same `ORA-00911` error as above.

Comment: @ScottMikutsky - yes, I said not with that syntax. You can't run DDL directly in PL/SQL; when you run it through `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` it's still running in a SQL context, so still doesn't know about the PL/SQL `%TYPE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use [%TYPE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/type_attribute.htm#LNPLS01352) in SQL.

For your alter table example you could use PL/SQL, but you will need to extract the data type information from the data dictionary, something like:

```
declare
  stmt varchar2(4000);
begin
  select 'alter table table_name add column_name ' ||
data_type || case 
    when data_type in ('NVARCHAR2', 'CHAR', 'TIMESTAMP')
      then '(' || data_length || ')'
    when data_type in ('VARCHAR2')
      then '(' || char_length || case when char_used = 'C' then ' CHAR' else ' BYTE' end || ')'
    when data_type in ('NUMBER')
        and (data_precision is not null or data_scale is not null)
      then '(' || data_precision || case
        when data_scale > 0 then ',' || data_scale
      end || ')'
    -- handling for other types
    end
  into stmt
  from user_tab_columns
  where table_name = 'ANOTHER_TABLE'
  and column_name = 'COLUMN_NAME';

  dbms_output.put_line(stmt);
  execute immediate stmt;
end;
/
```

That would produce and execute a statement like:

```
alter table table_name add column_name VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)
```

Which isn't pretty, and some data types - particularly UDTs - might give you headaches. You could turn that into a procedure though, and pass in the two table names and column names. You could also test whether the column exists in the target table already, and if so if it's the expected type, etc.